# addEventListener click

Tags: javascript, html

I start some beginner tutorials at this point screen should change after clicking on the button with the number but it all the time 0. Working on it a few hours. Some tips where I should look for mistakes?

```js
let buffer = "0";


const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");

document
    .querySelector(".calc-buttons")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
    });

function buttonClick(value) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))){
        handleSymbol(value);
    } else {
        handleNumber(value);
    }
}


function handleNumber(value){
    
    if (buffer === "0"){
        buffer = value;
    } else {
        buffer += value;
    }
    rerender();
}

function handleSymbol(value){

}

function rerender() {
    screen.innerText = buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```js
let buffer = "0";


const screen = document.querySelector(".screen");

document
    .querySelector(".calc-buttons")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
    });

function buttonClick(value) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))){
        handleSymbol(value);
    } else {
        handleNumber(value);
    }
}


function handleNumber(value){
    
    if (buffer === "0"){
        buffer = value;
    } else {
        buffer += value;
    }
    rerender();
}

function handleSymbol(value){

}

function rerender() {
    screen.innerText = buffer;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen"></div>
<div class="calc-buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer i found mistake. (facepalm)  My tag </section> with buttons was i wrong place that why it didnt work properly

Comment: We would have found this a lot faster if you had included the HTML in the question.